# Using file dialog in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-server, modelbuilder, geoprocessing-service, arcgis-flex-viewer

Is there a way to have the file dialog come up and let a user choose a file name and location for output?  I have the table to Excel script as an geoprocessing tool in the Flex Viewer and would like to have the user select the file name and location rather than use hard coded ones.

Comment: The Online Help about [Authoring geoprocessing tasks with ModelBuilder](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Authoring_geoprocessing_tasks_with_ModelBuilder/00570000007s000000/) is well worth reviewing, if you have not already.

Answer (score 1):

When you drag tools from ArcToolbox into the modelbuilder, you should be able to choose file dialog outputs.